# Map to generate multiple instances of destination message

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

First question :)

Below you will see a pic of my map that I have created. I am mapping the TransHeader record (grandchild of dataset, child of row) to a destination schema that will be tied to a send port (WCF-SQL to call a stored procedure).

When I use that send port, only the first instance of the TransHeader record is mapped and sent to SQL server. Obviously by looking at the schema, you can tell that multiple TransHeaders may exist in my inbound schema. I want to insert each instance.

Any thoughts?

pic:

[image: http://imgur.com/zgDqZ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a composite schema to wrap your WCF-SQL request and use a composite operation on the send port to execute these multiple requests.

Basically, you wrap your `usp_InsertTransHeader` request and response in a composite schema and mark the MaxOccurs to "unbounded" for the request and response.

This link,  [Composite Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788136%28v=bts.10%29.aspx), should provide a good guide on how to achieve this.

Also, look out for Richard Seroters example in his book; 
[SOA Patterns With BizTalk 2009](http://www.amazon.co.uk/SOA-Patterns-BizTalk-Server-2009/dp/1847195008)

HTH

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, this was perfect.

Comment: Anyone else having problems, remember to set the SOAP Action header Action: to CompositeOperation. This link helped me: http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_blogs/b/biztalksyn/archive/2009/03/30/walkthrough-composite-operations-with-the-new-wcf-based-sql-adapter.aspx